# What should be the response of FindEquationalProof?

Tags: theorem-proving

The code

```
grouptheory = {ForAll[{a, b, c}, g[a, g[b, c]] == g[g[a, b], c]], 
ForAll[a, g[a, e] == a], ForAll[a, g[a, inv[a]] == e]};
proof = FindEquationalProof[ForAll[{x, y}, g[y, x] == g[x, y]],grouptheory]
```

is running in 13.2 on Windows 10 without any response for hours, not exhausting the resources of my comp. The theorem is false (There are non-Abelian groups.), therefore it cannot be proven. I think that Mathematica should produce a message "FindEquationalProof cannot prove it" and return the input in moderate time, similarly to the behavior of `Reduce`,`Solve`,`FindInstance`, and other commands.

What are the suggestions of other users?

Comment: `FindEquationalProof[a == c, a == b]` returns a `Failure` object (_The proposition could not be reduced to True._). Also, in the documentation it says _By default, `FindEquationalProof` looks for a proof indefinitely._, and you can use `TimeConstraint` option.

Comment: @Domen: Thank you for your interest to the question.  What is the type of `a == c, a == b`? Is that syntactically correct at all?

Comment: Please read about [_What topics can I ask about here?_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): It says that the title of the question should succintly summarize your problem. _What should be the response?_ says nothing about the topic you are asking. If you do not like my proposal, please find another one. As for my code in the previous comment: It is the third example under `Scope` in the documentation for [`FindEquationalProof`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEquationalProof.html).

Comment: @Domen: Let us  imagine we don't know the logical value of the theorem. I find 
 the `TimeConstraint` option a good choice here. Can you kindly present it as an answer?

Comment: The same issue with `FindEquationalProof[a != c, {a == b, b == c}]`.